# Unsuscribe to WP7 notification for uninstalled application

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I have a toast notification system that is working on WP7. When I send a notification, all registered devices receive the toast notification.

But, If someone uninstall the application, I will continue to try to send to the registered device (in fact, I will ask Microsoft service to send to the unavailable device).
Is it possible to detect if someone uninstall the app, then I can remove it from my list of device to send.
Or maybe can Ms services tell me if the app as unsuscribe to the toast notification ?

My list of registered device grows infinitely ....

Thanks in advance for any Help,
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't detect if the user deleted the app, but can always check the subscription status return code when you send a notification!

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941100%28VS.92%29.aspx) for the return codes, specifically where the SubscriptionStatus != Active